# onPress isn't reading the handler functions

Tags: react-native, post, event-handling, react-native-flatlist, onpress

I'm trying to pass two things into my on press functions. The first part sets state to id of the element that was clicked, which in turn I will need for the second function (a POST request).The set state is successful, but the POST request is never even hit. I need to keep the setState part inside the onPress because it's the only place I have access to the item that is clicked. Any ideas why the second function isn't being hit? Any workarounds? I'm relatively new to react native so any ideas will be very helpful. Thanks!

```
handlePress=()=> {
    debugger
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/user_resources', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Accept: 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              resource_id: this.state.eventId,
              user_id: this.props.users.id
          })
      })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data2 => {
              this.props.addUserResource(data2)
          })
  }

  header = () => {
  return <Text style={styles.header}>Hello, {this.props.users.name}</Text>
  }
 
  render(){
    console.log(this.state)
     return(
       <>
      <Button title="Add A New Resource" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Add A New Resource',{topicId:this.props.route.params.topicId})} style={styles.listitem} />
      <FlatList style={styles.flatlist} keyExtractor={(item)=> item.id.toString()} data={anoda} ItemSeparatorComponent = { this.FlatListItemSeparator } renderItem={({item}) => {
       return <TouchableOpacity><Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Add A New Resource',{topicId:item.id})} style={styles.listitem}>{item.name}</Text><Button title="worku?" onPress={()=> {this.setState({eventId:item.id})}}/></TouchableOpacity>
      }
    }
      ListHeaderComponent = {this.header}/>
     </>)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I didn't find any code where you are calling `this.handlePress`. On both `onPress` you are navigating it to new screen.

Comment: @praveen-me hey within the line that there's a touchable opacity there's another button towards the end that's where I'm having the issue